# Nested Map operation in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Maps of type

```
Map<String,Map<String,bool>> outerMap;
Map<String,bool> innerMap_1 ,innerMap_2;
```

I need to nest innerMaps inside outerMap.

```
innerMap_1 = { 'time_1':true , 'time_2':false };
innerMap_1 = { 'time_3':false ,'time_4':true };

outerMap = { 'date_1':innerMap_1 , 'date_2':innerMap2 };
```

I need to store outerMap as a string on the Sqlite Database. When I try

```
jsonEncode(outerMap);
```

There is an error because it is nested.

**How to effectively convert the outerMap to String and then convert that string back to Map ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
outerMap = { 'date_1':innerMap_1 , 'date_2':innerMap2 };
```

The thing is that you had a spelling error and therefore there was an error. But in my solution I fixed that.

Another thing to notice is that in order to use the `jsonEncode` function you have to import the `dart:convert` package.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  Map<String, Map<String, bool>> outerMap;
  Map<String, bool> innerMap_1, innerMap_2;

  innerMap_1 = {'time_1': true, 'time_2': false};
  innerMap_2 = {'time_3': false, 'time_4': true};

  outerMap = {'date_1': innerMap_1, 'date_2': innerMap_2};
  
  String json = jsonEncode(outerMap);
  print(json);
  print(jsonDecode(json));
}
```

You can test your dart code on [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/).